# What is the right way to wait for MoveTo action to be completed?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, cocossharp

I created an app that is essentially a rippof of candy crush using CocosSharp, which is something that I'm actually using for the first time, same for C# and Xamarin. To do the animations I'm using the provided MoveTo method, but I'm not sure how I should be going about to wait for the animations to complete before continuing with my code. Currently I'm using await Task.Delay() in conjunction with while loops to accomplish this, but this "feels" and looks "dirty". I was wondering what is the proper way of waiting for the animations to complete?

Here's a bit of code that I've written:

```
//  Checks to see if a swap is possible, if it is then it will do so
    //  otherwise it will call for a failed swap animation
    public async void trySwap(int horzDelta, int vertDelta, int fromRow, int fromCol)
    {
        //debugLabel.Text = "checking to see if a swap is possible.";
        int toRow = fromRow + vertDelta;
        int toCol = fromCol + horzDelta;

        //  Make sure that the user didn't swipe out of the grid as there isn't any candies to swap with out there
        if (toRow < 0 || toRow >= gridRows)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (toCol < 0 || toCol >= gridColumns)
        {
            return;
        }

        candy toCandy = candyAt(toRow, toCol);
        candy fromCandy = candyAt(fromRow, fromCol);
        //debugLabel.Text = "Switching candy at [" + fromRow + ", " + fromCol + "] with candy at [" + toRow + ", " + toCol + "].";

        Swap swap = new Swap();
        swap.candyA = fromCandy;
        swap.candyB = toCandy;

        if (isSwapPossible(swap))
        {
            // Swap them
            animateSwap(swap);
            await Task.Delay(300);  // Wait for the swap animation to finish before continuing
            dropped = false;    // Sets dropped to false, it will be used to check if the game finished dropping all of the candies
            filledAgain = false;
            finishedRemoving = false;
            do
            {
                //  My reason to add the while loops with the awaits is that the App seems to come back to this do while even before the
                //  the method completely finish running. I'm guessing that awaits in the methods is forcing the App to continue running while it's awaiting
                //  to continue within the method. It's possible that the called methods are running on a separate threads from the thread that is running this
                //  method, so while those threads are put on hold, the App jumps back to this thread. After putting in while loops the app does seems to work like
                //  I want it to so I'm probably on the right track, thought there must be a better way to accomplish as the current way looks ugly.

                removeMatches();        // Remove the matches
                while (!finishedRemoving)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                }
                dropCandies();          // Move the candies down
                while (!dropped)        // As long as the dropCandies method isn't finished it will keep adding an await
                {
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                }
                fillUpColumns();        // Fill the grid back up
                while (!filledAgain)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                }
                detectPossibleSwap();   // Need to update the list of possible swaps
                await Task.Delay(300);
            }
            while (deleteChains.Count != 0);
            decrementMoves();

            // In the case that grid ends up with no possible swaps, we need to refill the grid new candies
            if (possibleSwaps.Count == 0 && movesLeft != 0)
            {
                reshuffle();
                while (!doneShuffling)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //  failedSwapAnimation only needs to run if there's valid candies
            if (swap.candyA != null && swap.candyB != null)
            {
                //  Swap is not possible so run the failed swap animation
                failedSwapAnimation(swap);
                //  Waiting to make sure the animation has been completed
                await Task.Delay(300);
            }
            else
            {
                //  The method enables the user interaction again and returns the call point without any type of animation
                //  as the user tried to do a swap with an empty location
                enableListeners();
                return;
            }
        }
        //  Turn user interaction back on as all of the matches were removed and the grid filled back up
        if (movesLeft != 0)
        {
            enableListeners();
        }
    }
```

Here's the methods that actually are calling the MoveTo method:

```
//  Visually animates the swap using the CCMoveTo function provided by CocosSharp,
    //  also updates the grid location of the candies
    private void animateSwap(Swap swap)
    {
        const float timeToTake = 0.3f; // in seconds
        CCFiniteTimeAction coreAction = null;

        //  Store the positions of the candies to be used to swap them
        CCPoint positionA = new CCPoint(swap.candyA.Position);
        CCPoint positionB = new CCPoint(swap.candyB.Position);

        //  Animate the swapping of the candies
        coreAction = new CCMoveTo(timeToTake, positionB);
        swap.candyA.AddAction(coreAction);
        coreAction = new CCMoveTo(timeToTake, positionA);
        swap.candyB.AddAction(coreAction);

        //  Update the row and column positions for each candy
        swap.candyA.setPosition(convertYToRow(positionB.Y), convertXToColumn(positionB.X));
        swap.candyB.setPosition(convertYToRow(positionA.Y), convertXToColumn(positionA.X));

        //  Update the position of the candies within the grid
        grid[swap.candyA.getRow(), swap.candyA.getColumn()] = swap.candyA;
        grid[swap.candyB.getRow(), swap.candyB.getColumn()] = swap.candyB;
    }

    //  Animation for a failed swap
    private async void failedSwapAnimation(Swap swap)
    {
        const float timeToTake = 0.1f; // in seconds
        CCFiniteTimeAction coreAction = null;
        CCFiniteTimeAction secondAction = null;

        //  Store the positions of the candies to be used to swap them
        CCPoint positionA = new CCPoint(swap.candyA.Position);
        CCPoint positionB = new CCPoint(swap.candyB.Position);

        //  Animate moving the candies back and forth
        coreAction = new CCMoveTo(timeToTake, positionB);
        secondAction = new CCMoveTo(timeToTake, positionA);
        swap.candyA.RunActions(coreAction, secondAction);
        coreAction = new CCMoveTo(timeToTake, positionA);
        secondAction = new CCMoveTo(timeToTake, positionB);
        swap.candyB.RunActions(coreAction, secondAction);

        //  Wait for the animation to complete before moving on
        await Task.Delay(300);
    }

    //  Method to find all chains in the grid 
    private void removeMatches()
    {
        List<Chain> horizontalChains = detectHorizontalMatches();
        List<Chain> verticalChains = detectVerticalMatches();

        // Logic to remove the candies from the grid goes here, possibly call a method that takes the list of chains to work with
        // Don't forget that candies have to be removed from the grid and then afterwards the sprites need to be removed from the screen separately
        // which can be handle by another method
        foreach (Chain item in verticalChains)
        {
            horizontalChains.Add(item);
        }
        deleteChains = horizontalChains;
        removeCandies(horizontalChains);
    }

    //  Remove the candy objects from the screen and the grid
    private async void removeCandies(List<Chain> chains)
    {
        if (finishedRemoving != false)
        {
            finishedRemoving = false;
        }

        foreach (Chain chain in chains)
        {
            foreach (candy candy in chain.candies)
            {
                //  Remove the candy from the grid
                grid[candy.getRow(), candy.getColumn()] = null;
                CCSprite removeCandy = candy.getSprite();
                if (removeCandy != null)
                {
                    const float timeToTake = 0.3f; // in seconds
                    CCFiniteTimeAction coreAction = null;
                    CCAction easing = null;

                    coreAction = new CCScaleTo(timeToTake, 0.3f);
                    easing = new CCEaseOut(coreAction, 0.1f);
                    removeCandy.RunAction(coreAction);

                    await Task.Delay(50);   // Wait for the scaling animation to show a bit before continuing on to remove the candy
                    //pointGone = false;
                    //pointLabel(candy.getRow(), candy.getColumn());
                    //while (!pointGone)
                    //{
                    //    await Task.Delay(1);
                    //}
                    removeCandy.RemoveFromParent(); // This should remove the candy from the screen
                    handlePoints();
                }
            }
            //  Wait for all of the candies to be removed before moving on to the next chain in the list of chains
            await Task.Delay(300);
        }
        //  Since the method is finished removing all of chains, needed to set the finishedRemoving bool variable to true
        //  so the calling method can get out of it's await loop
        finishedRemoving = true;
    }

    //  Drops the candies down 
    private async void dropCandies()
    {
        // Makes sure that dropped bool variable is set false before continuing
        if (dropped != false)
        {
            dropped = false;
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < gridColumns; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 8; row > 0; row--)
            {
                if (level.tiles[row, col] == 1)
                {
                    candy Candy = candyAt(row, col);
                    if (Candy == null)
                    {
                        // Find which row number to drop the candy from
                        int tempRow = row - 1;
                        while (tempRow >= 0 && grid[tempRow, col] == null)
                        {
                            tempRow--;
                        }
                        //  Only runs if there's a row that has a candy in it
                        if (tempRow >= 0)
                        {
                            CCPoint position = new CCPoint(70 + (62 * col), 810 - (70 * row));
                            Candy = candyAt(tempRow, col);
                            Candy.AddAction(new CCEaseOut(new CCMoveTo(0.3f, position), 0.3f));
                            Candy.setPosition(row, col);    // Update the row and column of the candy
                            grid[row, col] = Candy;             // Update the position of the candy within the grid
                            grid[tempRow, col] = null;
                            //  Wait for the candy to drop before moving to on the next candy
                            await Task.Delay(50);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Since the method should have gone through the entire grid and finished dropping the candies
        // need to set dropped to true so the calling method can get out of the await loop
        dropped = true;
    }

    //  Fill the holes at the top of the of each column
    private void fillUpColumns()
    {
        int candyType = 0;
        if (filledAgain != false)
        {
            filledAgain = false;
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < gridColumns; col++)
        {
            //  Starting at the top and working downwards, add a new candy where it's needed
            for (int row = 0; row < gridRows && grid[row, col] == null; row++)
            {
                if (level.tiles[row, col] == 1)
                {
                    int newCandyType = 0;
                    //  Have to first create a new candy outside of the while loop or otherwise the IDE won't let me use the variable newCandy
                    //  as it will be seen as using an unassigned variable, even though it will be assigned a new candy in the while loop
                    candy newCandy = new candy(rand, row, col);
                    newCandyType = newCandy.getType();
                    //  Make sure that each candy that is being added isn't the same as the one that was added previously
                    while (newCandyType == candyType)
                    {
                        newCandy = new candy(rand, row, col);
                        newCandyType = newCandy.getType();
                    }
                    candyType = newCandyType;
                    grid[row, col] = newCandy;

                    // Once all of the candy is created to fill the grid back up
                    // Use an animation to add it to the screen
                    animateAddingNewCandies(row, col);
                }
            }
        }
        //  Since the entire grid was filled back up with candies, need to set the filledAgain bool variable to true
        //  so the calling method can get out the await loop
        filledAgain = true;
    }
```

For those that want to see the full code to better understand the problem, I can post the github link here. I won't include it now as I'm not sure if that's actually allowed or not. Sorry about some of the comments as some of them are just me writing down my thoughts at the time.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41912/wait-till-all-ccactions-have-completed

Answer (score 3):

I would use a sequence with CCMoveTo and a CCCallFunc

```
var moveAction = new CCMoveTo(1.0f, someplace);
var moveCompletedAction = new CCCallFunc(this.FunctionToCallWhenMoveIsComplete);
CCSequence mySequence = new CCSequence(moveAction, moveCompletedAction);
mysprite.RunAction(mySequence);


....

void FunctionToCallWhenMoveIsComplete ()
{
    // run your post move code here
}
```